# Build get failed while migrating android project to AndroidX

Tags: android, gradle, lombok, androidx

My project is using lombok library. I am trying to migrate my project to AndroidX. But its build failed with below exception.

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
Failed to transform file 'lombok-1.18.4.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar} using transform JetifyTransform
        Failed to transform '/Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.18.4/7103ab519b1cdbb0642ad4eaf1db209d905d0f96/lombok-1.18.4.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: The type does not support '.' as package separator!. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.) To disable Jetifier, set android.enableJetifier=false in your gradle.properties file.

        * Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

        * Exception is: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1013)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1700(DefaultConfiguration.java:123)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:987)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:76)
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.transform.ArtifactTransformException: Failed to transform file 'lombok-1.18.4.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar} using transform JetifyTransform
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.UserCodeBackedTransformer.transform(UserCodeBackedTransformer.java:89)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.ChainedTransformer.transform(ChainedTransformer.java:36)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformArtifactOperation.run(TransformArtifactOperation.java:41)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.UserCodeBackedTransformer.transform(UserCodeBackedTransformer.java:87)
                ... 17 more 
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The type does not support '.' as package separator!
                at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.core.type.JavaType.<init>(JavaType.kt:28)
                at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.transform.bytecode.asm.CustomRemapper.map(CustomRemapper.kt:29)
                at org.objectweb.asm.commons.Remapper.mapPackageName(Remapper.java:235)
                at org.objectweb.asm.commons.ModuleRemapper.visitExport(ModuleRemapper.java:78)
                at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:774)
                at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:632)
                at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
                at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.transform.bytecode.ByteCodeTransformer.runTransform(ByteCodeTransformer.kt:39)
                at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.visit(Processor.kt:328)
                at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.archive.ArchiveFile.accept(ArchiveFile.kt:41)
                at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.visit(Processor.kt:316)
                at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.archive.Archive.accept(Archive.kt:66)
                at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.transformLibrary(Processor.kt:312)
                at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.transform(Processor.kt:175)
                at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.JetifyTransform.transform(JetifyTransform.kt:199)
                ... 39 more
```

Here is my gradle.properties file

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2560M
pgiMixpanelToken="null"
pgiProdApiKey="null"
android.databinding.enableV2=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Hey, can you please show your `gradle.properties file`?

Comment: @nimi0112 Thanks for the support.
I have updated my question with gradle.properties file.
Note: I have migrated the project using android studio -> Refactor-> Migrate to AndroidX

Comment: try `android.enableJetifier false` as mentioned in your error log.